# Get all the rows from the right joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys

I am struggling to get the output in the following format:
e.g.

```
| Total | Roles | Month | Year |
--------------------------------
| 52    | Admin |January| 2012 |
| 0     | Tester|July   | 2012 |
| 41    | HR    |January| 2014 |
| 0     | TL    |June   | 2015 |
| 14    | VP    |March  | 2011 |
```

I am having two tables (say users and userType), here "type" column in users table is reference to userType table.

I want to get all the rows from right joined table and if there are no values in the left table then it should display "0".

Please view below which I have tried:

```
SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(u.`userId`),0) AS 'Total',r.`roleName` AS 'Role',COALESCE(MONTH(u.`userOn`),0) AS 'Month', COALESCE(YEAR(u.`userOn`),0) AS 'Year' FROM `users` u RIGHT JOIN `usertype` r ON u.`userRole` = r.`roleId` WHERE YEAR(`userOn`) > 2011 and u.`userRole` = r.`roleId` GROUP by r.`roleName`;
```

How to get the query for the provided output?

Comment: Note that nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Put your `YEAR(userOn) > 2011` condition in `ON Clause` like below

```
SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(u.`userId`),0) AS 'Total',r.`roleName` AS 'Role' 
FROM `usertype` r left join `users` u ON u.`userRole` = r.`roleId` 
and YEAR(`userOn`) > 2011
GROUP by r.`roleName`;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Coalesce` is not required and you can do `right join` as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(u.`userId`) AS 'Total',
       r.`roleName` AS 'Role' 
 FROM `users` u 
 RIGHT JOIN `usertype` r ON u.`userRole` = r.`roleId` 
                        and YEAR(u.`userOn`) > 2011
GROUP by r.`roleName`;
```

You will have to write the condition  `YEAR(u.userOn) > 2011` in `ON` clause

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to solve this with a subquery.
Something like this:

```
Select 
    (select count(*) from users where userRole=roleId and YEAR(`userOn`) > 2011),
    rolename as Role
from  usertype
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions cannot use indexes, so if useron is part of an index (and it certainly should be) then something like this will be more efficient:

```
SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(u.userId),0)  Total
     , r.roleName Role
  FROM usertype r
  LEFT 
  JOIN users u
    ON u.userRole = r.roleId
   AND u.userOn >= '2011-01-01'
 GROUP 
    BY r.roleName
```

An index on some combination of (userOn,userRole) seems sensible